# Spring Social Login: How to add more than one app of the same social provider (f.e. Facebook)?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook, spring-social-google

My Spring MVC web application is serving simultanously three different web shops with three different domains (let's call them domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com).

For each of these shops I need to offer an own Social Login (with custom login screen title, custom data privacy statement, ...). Therefore I need to create three different social provider (f.e. facebook) apps.

In Spring Social - from my understanding - I'm allowed to add only one `FacebookConnectionFactory` and hereby only one provider app.

How can I despite that add these three different facebook apps to Spring Social? Is Spring Social capable to manage this? Are there workarounds existing?

Answer (score 0):

May be I answered too late for the OP but this could be usefull for other developers.
I implemented a workaround for this issue defining my own "Registries" as follow:

```
<bean id="myConnectionFactoryRegistries" class="package.ShopsFactoryRegistries">
    <property name="registries">
    <map key-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="shop1Key" value-ref="connectionFactoryRegistryShop1" />
        <entry key="shop2Key" value-ref="connectionFactoryRegistryShop2" />
    </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactoryRegistryShop1"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.apikey.shop1}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.apisecret.shop1}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactoryRegistryShop2"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.apikey.shop2}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.apisecret.shop2}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And implement a factory in order to retrieve the proper `ConnectionFactoryRegistry` related to the "current" shop (identified by the shopKey).

```
public class ShopsFactoryRegistries
{
    private Map<String, ConnectionFactoryRegistry> registries;

    public ConnectionFactoryRegistry getRegistryForShopKey(String shopKey)
    {
        return registries.get(shopKey);
    }

    //getter and setter for registries
}
```

With this code you can retrieve the facebookConnectionFactory for the `shop1`:

```
String shopKey = "shop1Key";
FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory = (FacebookConnectionFactory) myConnectionFactoryRegistries.getRegistryForShopKey(shopKey).getConnectionFactory(FACEBOOK);
```